# HLS Pull no m3u8 file

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Currently trying to implement HLS into my NGINX. I am trying to open the stream in my browser. I am also using a "pull" for the stream, so i would re-stream the RTMP source, which is currently not working.

My nginx configuration file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            pull rtmp://<STREAM_PULL_IP_ADDR>:1935/rtplive live=1;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /tmp/;
        }
    }
}
```

Website that shows the stream:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls preload="none">
    <source src="http://<MY_IP_ADDR>:8080/hls/stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
<script>
    var player = videojs('#player');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also i can not call my URL with /hls/stream.m3u8 because it ends up in nginx error:
`28654#0: *2 open() "/tmp/hls/stream.m3u8" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: <VISITOR_IP>, server: , request: "GET /hls/stream.m3u8 HTTP/1.1"`

The websites code is delivered by apache2, hosted on the same server. I don't think that's a problem, because the stream.m3u8 url leads into an NGINX error. So the URL can be called within the NGINX environment.

Update:
After calling the nginx URL directly (/hls), the error log prints:
`31872#0: *4 directory index of "/tmp/hls/" is forbidden, client: <VISITOR_IP_ADDR>, server:` but the directory has the permission 1777 for the www-data, which is the nginx user.

Comment: I have also the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: m3u8 file appears only when a valid stream is sent to the rtmp server. You have to use some sort of publisher to get the stream running. OBS for example.